# How l can stop the timer in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want when the user click submit the timer stop
when l add **clearInterval**  l have error

my code :

```
  <html>
  <body>
  <button onclick="myStopFunction()">submit</button>
<div><span id="time">01:00</span> minutes!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">



    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration,
            minutes, seconds;
                 var handle = setInterval(function() {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10) //10 the ten system 
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;


    }   

    function myStopFunction() {
clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Comment: Move `var handle` outside the startTimer function., and change `clearInterval(myVar);` to `clearInterval(handle);`

Comment: What do you think `myVar` refers to? Where is it declared?

Comment: `clearInterval(myVar);` should be `clearInterval(handle);` and `handle` should be declared globally outside of `startTimer` or returned to a global variable that `myStopFunction` can reach.

Comment: Are you ever calling `startTimer` somewhere?

Comment: Follow the flow of execution of code to understand your mistake.

Comment: @Bergi  yes l call it      window.onload = function() {
            var threrMinutes = 60 * 1 // change the mintue from here
                display = document.querySelector('#time');
            startTimer(threrMinutes, display);
        };

Answer (score 2):

You should have intervalHandle outside of startTimer scope. It is good practice to create closure (like below) to not polute global scope with variables that are not required to be exposed.

Please remember to call startTimer.

You could have solution like below:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">submit</button>
<div><span id="time">01:00</span> minutes!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() { //create closure to not polute global scope
        var intervalHandle;

        function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration,
                    minutes, seconds;

            //assign interval handle to outer scope
            intervalHandle = setInterval(function() {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10); //10 the ten system
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
                display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            }, timer);
        }

        function myStopFunction() {
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        }

        // export functions to global scope
        window.startTimer = startTimer;
        window.myStopFunction = myStopFunction;
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Happy hacking!

Comment: sorry, forgot to add second argument of setInterval. Updated post

Comment: the timer still not work , can you try it in your editor , please ?

Comment: when l  click show error (  myStopFunction is not defined ) !!

Comment: I have modified interval to console.log(Date.now()) like here: intervalHandle = setInterval(function() {/**rest of code*/console.log(Date.now());});

Then I copied whole script from <script> tag and pasted in into google chrome dev tools console.

And when I enter `startTimer(1000, document.querySelector('body'))` In console it will replace whole body of current page (eg. stack overflow) and display time. In console it shows each second result of Date.now()

When I call `myStopFunction()` it stops logging on console.

So my code works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your var `handle` which contains the `setInterval` function exists only in his scope : the function `startTimer`.
So, just declare `var handle;` out of your functions and call `clearInterval(handle);` in the stop function
(and obviously keep `handle = setInterval(function() {...}` in your code).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
<p id="test">

</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>


</body>
</html>




  var count = 0;
var myVar;
  function start() {
    myVar = setInterval(function() {
      console.log('hi');
      $('#test').text('hi' + count++);
    }, 1000);
    return myVar;
  }


  function stop() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
```

Comment: @Bergi if I'll create a variable `myVar` outside then it will be global.

Comment: Outside of what? The snippet you posted *does* create a global variable, and at the same time you advise to avoid it.

Comment: l try to do this but when l click  timer dose not stop

Comment: @malakjameel can you please create a fiddle to demonstrate.